# Select column names not in list of names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of column names from a dataframe and would like to generate a second list of column names that excludes everything in that first list.

I was thinking something like features=x[~x[exclude_features]].columns

(where exclude_features is a list of column names to exclude, but that throws an error. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try

```
features=x.loc[:, ~x.columns.isin(exclude_features)].copy()
```

Or

```
features=x.loc[:, x.columns.difference(exclude_features)].copy()
```